# Fulltext search against table row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am trying to highlight a maximum of 2 words inside a given text. The search keywords come from a mysql table with several hundred possible matches and information on importance.

e.g.:  "The cracy fox jumps over the red cow"

mysql table "words" with possible matches:

```
keyword  importance
bird     0,2
fox      0,5
cow      0,1
red      0,4
```

The query should return fox and red.

something like this:

```
SELECT keyword
from db.words
WHERE keyword matches ('The cracy fox jumps over the red cow')
ORDER BY importance
LIMIT 2
```

Thank you for any hint on how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind outputing the importance:

```
SELECT keyword, match(keyword) against ('The cracy fox jumps over the red cow') as importance
from db.words
WHERE match(keyword) against ('The cracy fox jumps over the red cow')
ORDER BY importance
LIMIT 2;
```

Otherwise, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM (SELECT keyword, match(keyword) against ('The cracy fox jumps over the red cow') as importance
      from db.words
      WHERE match(keyword) against ('The cracy fox jumps over the red cow')
      ORDER BY importance
      LIMIT 2
     ) k;
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. Are you sure that the command "matches" exists in mysql 5.x ? I could not find any example of this syntax and mysql tells me that the command is unknown.

Comment: @merlin . . . Thank you .  The syntax was obviously off.  I was focused on getting the condition into the `where` clause.